# System.OverflowException when calling System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()

Tags: c#, windows, activex, ocx, winforms-interop

I have a C# WPF project that uses (non-graphical) Active X controllers which are wrapped in a Windows Forms controls generated by [Aximp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost(v=vs.110).aspx)  from a OCX-file (I don't have access to the it's source code).

When instantiating one of the controllers using the following code:

```
        // Create the interop host controls.
        var hostProq = new WindowsFormsHost();
        _AxProq = new AxProOCX.AxProq();
        hostProq.Child = _AxProq;
        _AxProq.CreateControl();
```

a `System.OverflowException` is thrown when calling `CreateControl()`. The call stack looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(string license, System.Guid clsid)    
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(System.Guid clsid)   
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()    
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()  
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(int state = 2)   
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()  
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible = false) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
```

The OCX-file seems to be installed and registered properly because certain other controls in it works and this specific control can be used in [ActiveX Control Test Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost(v=vs.110).aspx). An earlier version of the control works and this used to work a few weeks ago.

The environment is Windows 10 Pro with Visual studio 2015.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the exception.
Is the exception caused by the wrapper or inside the ActiveX controller?
What can cause the control to work in ActiveX Control Test Container but not my application?

Comment: Have you tried opening the library in ILSpy? At least the wrapper .Net class you are working with.

Comment: Well, that does not exactly look like a stack that overflowed, that makes it very hard to help you.  Do note that you are doing this fundamentally wrong, you must only ever use Aximp.exe and a WindowsFormsHost on a real ActiveX control, the kind that are "graphical".  In other words, have a visual representation on your UI.  Non-graphical COM components merely require Tlbimp.exe and a simple `new` statement to initialize.  Use a telephone to get help from the component author or vendor.

Comment: Ok, suddenly it has began working again, I have no idea why. I will look into ILSpy if it returns and also read up on Tlbimp to see if I can make future improvments.

Comment: The error has reappeared intermittently. I have tried using Tlbimp.exe instead of Aximp.exe but can't use `new`, error says "Cannot access internal constructor here". If I use Olveview.exe I can see that the class has the `noncreatable` and `control` attributes set.